# Reliable way to set DNS

Tags: internet

I have an LG P880 phone on 4.2 and a 2013 Nexus 7 on 4.4. I use 2G, 3G and Wifi for the phone. I am experimenting with changing the DNS to Google's. I do notice that the ISP (Wifi of course) DNS performance is unacceptable.

Which is an app that allows me to set DNS with minimum drama: no random failures, no need of root, no interception of traffic (one app creates a VPN)?

Answer (score 0):

Go into WiFi Settings > (Press and hold) the preferred network connection > (Click) Modify network config > (Check) Show advance options > (Select) Static (instead of DHCP) > [Under DSN 1 and DSN 2 enter your choice) > (Click) Save

This will work for wifi.  I don't think it will change the DNS provided by your phone carrier.

When you specify static you are overriding the DHCP distribution of the router.  You would have to specify an IP address outside of the specified automatic range pool